# How do I create this feature in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

How do I create this feature in excel?

[image]

Comment: Could you add more information to your question to let us know what specifically you're looking for?

Comment: Indeed, as asked it is unclear. But in excel you can fold in/fold out rows and columns. I think the OP is asking for how to do this. The key word is how to [group] them. (see data tab). @OP, can you edit the question to make it clearer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is an [Outline (Group)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/outline-group-data-in-a-worksheet-08ce98c4-0063-4d42-8ac7-8278c49e9aff)

> If you have a list of data that you want to group and summarize, you can create an outline of up to eight levels, one for each group. Each inner level, represented by a higher number in the outline symbols, displays detail data for the preceding outer level, represented by a lower number in the outline symbols. Use an outline to quickly display summary rows or columns, or to reveal the detail data for each group. You can create an outline of rows (as shown in the example below), an outline of columns, or an outline of both rows and columns.

You can access it under the Data tab:

[image]